# Kernel language representation of a function

Tags: oz

What is the kernel language representation of `N + {Add N - 1}` following the stub

```
local I1 in

// the code

        end
    end
end
```

the procedure definition of function `{Add N}` is as follows

```
proc {Add N R}
    if N == 0 then R = 0
    else N + {Add N - 1}
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the kernel language, you have to define a new identifier for each operation. One for the `N-1` operation, another to retrieve the result of the procedure `Add` and a third one to store the result of `N + {Add N-1}`. Also you have to declare each local variable separately.

So you get something like this :

```
local I1 in
   local I2 in
      local I3 in
         I1 = 1
         I2 = N - I1
         {Add I2 I3}
         R = N + I3
      end
   end
end
```

Then `I3` contains the value `N + {Add N-1}`

Comment: even though your solution seems to work it does not give me the expected answer. To be exact the code body should contain 6 lines (10 lines including stub).

Comment: I was able to complete most of the code but missing to lines

`local I1 in`\n
    `local  N1 in`
        `local R1 in`
            `...`
            `...`
            `{Add N1 R1}`
           `R = N + R1`
        `end`
     `end`
`end`

Comment: Sorry you also have to declare the 1 as a variable in kernel language. All the basic operations have to be done on identifiers, not values. I edited the post

Answer (score 0):

You can get the kernel language of any piece of code with the Mozart IDE.

You juste have to go under the tab Oz > Core Syntax > Whatever piece of code you want translate into KL

It gives

```
declare Add in
local UnnestApply1 UnnestApply2 in
   proc {Add N Result1}
      local IfArbiter1 UnnestApply3 in
     UnnestApply3 = 0
     IfArbiter1 = N == UnnestApply3
     if IfArbiter1 then
        Result1 = 0
     else
        local UnnestApply4 UnnestApply5 UnnestApply6 in
           UnnestApply6 = 1
           UnnestApply5 = N - UnnestApply6
           {Add UnnestApply5 UnnestApply4}
           Result1 = N + UnnestApply4
        end
     end
      end
   end
   UnnestApply2 = 4
   {Add UnnestApply2 UnnestApply1}
   {Browse UnnestApply1}
end
```

It may be hard to read, but the tool is really helpful and powerful